# Need to change the startdate as per the month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table something like this. workershiftid column is auto-increment.

I have to create a job which runs on first of every month and change the start and end date accordingly rest all will be same.

`job`:

```
Workershiftid   |   entityid    |   startdate   |   enddate     |   shiftid 
1               |   1           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   1   
2               |   2           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   4   
3               |   4           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   6  
4               |   7           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   14
```

I tried this query:

```
insert into job (entityid, startdate, enddate, shiftid)
select entityid, startdate, enddate, shiftid 
from job 
where startdate = '2016-06-01'
```

But it is giving output as

```
Workershiftid   |   entityid    |   startdate   |   enddate     |   shiftid  
1               |   1           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   1   
2               |   2           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   4  
3               |   4           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   6  
4               |   7           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   14  
5               |   1           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   1   
6               |   2           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   4   
7               |   4           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   6  
8               |   7           |   2016-06-01  |   2016-06-30  |   14
```

How can I change the startdate to 2016-07-01 if I am running it on 1st July?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and last days of a month can be calculated like:

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0) AS StartOfMonth
SELECT DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0)) as EndOfMonth
```

So you can try something like this:

```
declare @start datetime
declare @end datetime

SELECT @start = DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, getdate()), 0)
SELECT @end = DATEADD(s,-1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(m,0,GETDATE())+1,0))

insert into job (entityid,startdate,startdate,shiftid)
select entityid,@start,@end,shiftid 
from job 
where startdate='2016-06-01'
```

Comment: It is giving me an error incorrect syntax near @start

Answer (score 0):

Use `GETDATE()` to know the current date

```
select entityid,startdate,enddate,shiftid 
from job where startdate=cast(getdate() as date)
```

`Getdate()` will result date with `time`. To remove time part from `getdate()` use `CAST`

In case you want to get the first day of current month then use this

```
Select CAST(DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE()), 0) AS DATE)
```